# Determining if a process is a martingale

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales, random-walk

Let $Z(t)$ be a standard brownian motion, given $W(t) = t^{2} Z(t) -2\int_0^t sZ(s) ds$ , determine if this is a martingale process!

We know that a process is martingale if $E[W(t+1)|F(t)] = W(t)$, with $F(t)$ as a filtration process. I think we should start by writing down $E[W(t+1)|F(t)]$ first, which is $E[(t+1)^{2} Z(t+1) -2\int_0^{t+1} sZ(s) ds|F(t)]$. This can be split into two terms:

First term: $E[(t+1)^{2} Z(t+1)|F(t)]$
which I believe would be $(t+1)^2Z(t)$, since a standard brownian motion is a martingale.

Second term: $-2E[\int_0^{t+1} sZ(s) ds|F(t)]$ 
for this part, i think we need to use integration by parts, but I ended up with $\int Z(s) ds$ and I'm not sure how to proceed with that result.

Am I doing the right steps? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I have not seen the definition of martingale(Continuous time) to be $E(X_{t+1}|\mathcal{F}_{t})=X_{t}$ .

The definition which is the  most standard is that for an adapted process $(X_{t})$ it is a martingale wrt $(\mathcal{F}_{t})$ if for all $s<t$, you have $E(X_{t}|\mathcal{F}_{s})=X_{s}$ . Obviously what you want follows from this definition, but I don't know whether the converse is true.

$E(W(t)|\mathcal{F}_{s})=E(t^{2}Z(t)|\mathcal{F}_{s})-2E(\int_{0}^{t}xZ(x)\,dx|\mathcal{F}_{s})$

Now $2\int_{0}^{t}xZ(x)\,dx = 2\int_{0}^{s}xZ(x)\,dx + 2\int_{s}^{t}xZ(x)\,dx$

So you have \begin{align}2E(\int_{s}^{t}xZ(x)\,dx|\mathcal{F}_{s})=2E((\int_{s}^{t}x(Z(x) -Z(s))\,dx|\mathcal{F}_{s})+(t^{2}-s^{2})Z(s)\end{align} Above, we have used that $E(Z_{s}|\mathcal{F}_{s})=Z_{s}$ and just added and substracted $\int_{s}^{t}x Z(s)\,dx$

Also you have $t^{2}Z(t)=t^{2}(Z(t)-Z(s))+t^{2}Z(s)$ and by Markov property $(Z(u)-Z(s))_{u\geq s}$ is a Standard Brownian Motion indepdendent of $\mathcal{F}_{s}$.

So we have:- $$E(W(t)|\mathcal{F}_{s})=t^{2}E(Z(t)-Z(s))+t^{2}Z(s)-2E(\int_{s}^{t}x(Z(x)-Z(s))\,dx)\\-(t^{2}-s^{2})Z(s)-2\int_{0}^{s}xZ(x)\,dx$$ where we have used independence to get rid of conditional expectation.

Simplyfying the above, and noting that $E(Z(t)-Z(s))=0$ you have

$$ s^{2}Z(s)-2\int_{0}^{s}xZ(x)\,dx-2E(\int_{s}^{t}x(Z(x)-Z(s))\,dx)$$

So it only remains to show that $E(\int_{s}^{t}x(Z(x)-Z(s))\,dx)=0$ but this is just due to Fubini's theorem,

$$E(\int_{s}^{t}xZ(x)-Z(s)\,dx)=\int_{\Omega}\int_{s}^{t}x(Z(x)(\omega)-Z(s)(\omega))\,dx\,d\mathbb{P}(\omega)$$

By Fubini,

$$=\int_{s}^{t}\int_{\Omega}x(Z(x)(\omega)-Z(s)(\omega))\,d\mathbb{P}(\omega)\,dx = 0$$

This is because $\int_{\Omega}(Z(x)(\omega)-Z(s)(\omega))\,d\mathbb{P}=E(Z(x)-Z(s))=0$ for each $x\in (s,t]$

And thats it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd reason like this. Define the function $f(t,Z_t) := t^2 Z_t$. By Ito's formula its differential is

$$
df = 2tZ_tdt + t^2dZ_t \Rightarrow 2\int_{0}^{t}sZ_s ds = t^2Z_t-\int_{0}^{t}s^2dZ_s
$$

Plugging this into our function $W_t$ we have

$$
W_t = \int_{0}^{t}s^2dZ_s \Rightarrow dW_t = t^2dZ_t
$$

This is a stochastic integral which is martingale since $t^2$ is $\mathcal{F}_t -$measurable and by Ito isometry $\mathbb{E}\bigg( \int_{0}^{t}s^2dZ_s\bigg)^2 < \infty$.

Thus the process is a martingale.

Comment: While your answer is very compact and neat(+1), I doubt if the op is familiar with Ito calculus. Its better to just use the definition of Martingales and basic properties of an SBM to solve this. But yes, others might find this helpful!

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron You may be right. In case he can revisit the answer once he gets accostumed to it